# Javadoc links to Oracle's API docs no longer working

Tags: java, javadoc

Using the Javadoc option `-link` I was previously able to have the generated docs link to the core Java API docs provided by oracle at `docs.oracle.com` (`-link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`), but now core classes are no longer linked.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the problem was using HTTP instead of HTTPS in the URL. Javadoc apparently can't handle the HTTP to HTTPS redirect the website provides.

Comment: Yes, they most likely withdrew that ... because using HTTP for this has privacy concerns.

Comment: Thank you! This had me perplexed.